Can't open Storyboard after migrating from Xamarin.iOS to .NET for iOS
I recently migrated my Xamarin.iOS project to .NET for iOS. Everything went fine so far. Now I'm realizing that I'm not able to work with storyboards anymore.
Before the migration I was working with Visual Studio for Mac. To modify storyboards I could just double click the file in VS4M and the storyboard opened up in Xcode with the corresponding temporary project (.h and .m files).
After the migration to .NET for iOS I had to switch to the regular Visual Studio for Windows 'cause .NET for iOS is not supported on VS4M.
Now when I try to open the storyboard in Xcode from VS (with my paired Mac) - Xcode opens up and I can see the storyboard but the corresponding .h and .m files are not created. So there is now way to modify or create IB outlets.
I tried to create a new plain project but even there it's not working. Xcode opens up but the storyboard is not connected - so no .h and .m files.
I still can open these .NET for iOS projects in VS4M and tried to open the storyboard from there - but also no luck.
When I reset my code to the point before I migrated the project everything works as expected again.
Any ideas on how to solve this issue?

Please provide more information like code or screenshot

I can only tell you that it's a bunch of bad news unless you have JetBrains Rider.
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-dotnettools/issues/571
It's not supported for now on both VS Mac or VS Code.

Thanks for the interesting link. But I actually don't want to use VS code. Regular VS 22 would be my first choice as Microsoft is proposing on their own website (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2022/what-happened-to-vs-for-mac). A while back I had a similar setup and I could edit the storyboard with syncing to VS on Windows. So I'm wondering if this is a setup issue right now or not supported for some reason after the migration to .NET for iOS

Vs for mac has retired and VS for windows cannot open storyboards for now... That's why I added that link it has that details as well
